# MOS chip dimensions

Tags: cpu, pinout, dimensions

I am looking for the physical dimensions to some chips used on the VIC20.

Looking at the datasheet http://www.6502.org/documents/datasheets/ the document is cryptic, not much conclusive because it represent multiple pins packages.

What are the dimensions in mm for

- 6502 40 pins (CPU)
- 6560-101 40 pins (VIC-Chip)
- 901486-x 24 pins (ROM)
- 65245 20 pin package (buss transceiver)

And are the RAM chips the same size of the ROM chips?

[image]

Comment: Is it the chips or the packages you're looking for?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Looking for the black block with the leads. Not the internal chip that is realy realy small.

Comment: All parts with the same pin count will be the same size, +/- manufactureing tolerances.  If a part has 24 pins, 12 on each side, it will be 12 x 0.1 inch = 1.2 inches long (plus 0.05 inch, or so).  A 40 pin part (20 pins each side) will be 20 x 0.1 = 2 inches long (plus 0.05 inch, or so).

Answer (score 0):

I expect that all the ICs in the VIC20 would be in conventional DIP packages.

Parts with 20 or fewer pins would have their pins in two rows 0.3 inch apart, with the pins in each row on 0.1 inch centers.

Parts with more than 20 pins would have the pin rows 0.6 inch apart.

The package would normally extend 0.05 inch or so beyond the end pins.

I think most RAM and ROM of that vintage were in 24 pin packages.

Comment: Looks like the description on the datasheet. It does not show the total height and width of the component. Can you include the width and height of the components themselves?

Comment: @ahwelp: the datasheet for the 2316 ROM does show the package dimensions on the last page. The molded (plastic) package is 0.530 to 0.550 inch wide, and 1.230 to 1.260 inches long.  That part was also available in a ceramic package with slightly different dimensions.  those dimensions would be typical for any 24 pin package.